# Question on a proof involving linked pairs and Green's relations. Characterisation of conjugacy of linked pairs

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages, semigroups

The following question comes from Proposition 2.7, Chapter II, form the book [Infinite words](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/Resumes/InfiniteWords.html) by D. Perrin and J.-E. Pin. I will give all the definitions after my question, so as to make this question self-contained.

> **Proposition 2.7.** Let $S$ be a finite semigroup. Two linked pairs $(s,e)$ and $(s', e')$ of $S$ are conjugate if and only if there exists $x \in S^1$ such that $s' = sx, xe'\mathcal R e$ and $e\mathcal D e'$.
>
> **Proof.** [...] Conversely, suppose there exists $x \in S^1$ such that $s' = sx, xe' \mathcal R e$ and $e \mathcal D e'$. Let $v \in S^1$ be such that $xe'v = e$. Then we have $xe' \mathcal R e = xe'v \mathcal Le'v \mathcal R e'$ and thus, by Proposition A.2.4. $h = (e'v)(xe') \mathcal H e'$. [...]

I do not understand the cited part of the proof? Maybe someone could give more details why $xe'v \mathcal L e'v$ and $e'v \mathcal R e'$ hold, and why this implies $(e'v)(xe')\mathcal He'$?

I give all the definitions. For a semigroup $S$, let $S^1 := S \cup \{1\}$ with $1s = s1 = s$ for all $s \in S$ if $S$ does not contains an identity, and $S^1 := S$ otherwise. Then we define [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations):
\begin{align*}
 s \mathcal R s' & :\Leftrightarrow sS^1 = s'S^1 \\
 s \mathcal L s' & :\Leftrightarrow S^1 s = S^1 s' \\
 s \mathcal J s' & :\Leftrightarrow S^1 s S^1 = S^1 s' S^1 \\
 s \mathcal D s' & :\Leftrightarrow s (\mathcal L \circ \mathcal R) s' \\
 s \mathcal H s' & :\Leftrightarrow s\mathcal R s' \mbox{ and } s\mathcal L s'
\end{align*}
These are all equivalence relations, and for $s \in S$ we denote by $R(s), L(s)$ and so on the equivalence class of $s$. Some properties as taken from the book:

- The relation $\mathcal R$ is stable on the left, and $\mathcal L$ is stable on the right
- If $e^2 = e \in S$ and $x \in S$ with $xS^1 \subseteq eS^1$, then $ex = x$ (and similar if $S^1x \subseteq S^1 e$ we have $xe = x$).
- $\mathcal L\circ \mathcal R = \mathcal R \circ \mathcal L$
- (**Proposition A.2.4. from the book**) Let $D$ be a $\mathcal D$-class of a semigroup $S$, and let $m,m'$ and $m''$ be elements of $S$.

  (1) If $m\mathcal R m'$ with $m = m'p, m' = mq$, the maps $x \mapsto xp$ and $x \mapsto xq$ define inverse bijections between $L(m)$ and $L(m')$, and these bijections preserve the $\mathcal H$-classes.

  (2) One has $mm'' \in R(m) \cap L(m'')$ if and only if $R(m'')\cap L(m)$ contains an idempotent.

  (3) An $\mathcal H$-class is a group if and only if it $H^2 \cap H \ne \emptyset$.

  (4) If $D$ contains an idempotent, it contains at least one idempotent in each $\mathcal R$-class and in each $\mathcal L$-class.
- If $S$ is finite we have

  (1) For $m \in S, r,s \in S^1$ if $m = rms$ then $rm \in L(m)$ and $ms \in R(m)$.

  (2) $m \mathcal D m' \Leftrightarrow m \mathcal J m'$.

  (3) If $m \mathcal J m'$ and $mS^1 \subseteq m'S^1$ then $m \mathcal R m'$, and if $m \mathcal J m'$ and $S^1 m \subseteq S^1 m'$ then $m \mathcal L m'$.

Now in a semigroup two elements $s,e \in S$ are called a *linked pair* if $e^2 = e$ and $se = s$. Two linked pairs $s,e$ and $s',e'$ are called conjugate if there exists $x,y \in S^1$ such that $e = xy, e' = yx$ and $s' = sx$ (which also implies $s = s'y$). This conjugacy relation is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, everything is contained in [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876272/show-that-the-h-class-from-greens-relations-contains-the-product-of-two-of-it/1876289#1876289) from me. In the question everything is stated in terms of monoids, without any reference to linked pairs.